# Use boost::optional together with boost::adaptors::indirected

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indirected.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  using namespace boost::assign;
  using boost::adaptors::indirected;

  std::vector<boost::optional<unsigned> > values;
  values += 1u,2u,3u;
  boost::copy( values | indirected, std::ostream_iterator<unsigned>( std::cout, " " ) );
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However, I got some errors, e.g. that there is no type named `element_type` in `boost::optional<unsigned>`. The [reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html) page, however, says that the single precondition is the existence of the `operator*()` unary function. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in Boost, but whether that bug is in Boost.Optional or Boost.Iterator is up for debate (I would say the latter, personally).

However, the fix is trivial -- before including any Boost headers, do this:

```
#include <boost/optional/optional_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/pointee.hpp>

namespace boost
{
    template<typename P>
    struct pointee<optional<P> >
    {
        typedef typename optional<P>::value_type type;
    };
}
```

Then include other Boost headers as necessary.

Please submit a ticket on the [Boost Trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/), or at the least post a bug report on the [Boost Users mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-users).

Comment: include header using <boost/optional/optional_fwd.hpp> is better.

Comment: @Akira : Good point; I forgot it was there since it's not in the root `boost` directory unlike most other Boost libs' forward declaration headers.

Comment: Rediscovering bugs that no-one bothered to report when told to is awesome. I independently found and reproduced this, resulting in this [trac ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5811).

Comment: @Lars: awesome indeed. I just did the same. However, as I quoted in a just posted answer this is probably by design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254131/is-it-possible-to-use-boostfilter-iterator-for-output/7254598#7254598

Answer (score 1):

Look at the private optional.hpp defined in boost iostreams library [here](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/iostreams/detail/optional.hpp). You will see that it defines a `typedef T element_type;`

However the actual optional.hpp that you are using defined [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) does not define it. So that is why the compiler is complaining. I don't know why it was overlooked.

Try using the private optional.hpp from iostreams library to solve this issue. I hope this helps.

Comment: Using classes/functions inside `detail` namespaces should **always** be a last resort; they're put there because they're specifically not intended for use outside of the given library's implementation.