# Is it possible to use boost::filter_iterator for output?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am using `std::transform` with an `std::back_inserter` to append elements to an `std::deque`.  Now the transformation may fail and will return a invalid object (say an uninitialized `boost::optional` or a null pointer) in some cases.  I would like to filter out the invalid objects from getting appended.

I thought about using `boost::filter_iterator`, but not sure how to present the `end()` parameter of the filtered range.

The documentation of `boost::filter_iterator` suggests that output filtering is possible.  Should I just specialize `operator ==` for `std::back_insert_iterator` in this case to always return false?

In addition to this, if I want to append values of initialized `boost::optional` or pointers, can I chain `boost::filter_iterator` and `boost::indirect_iterator`?

I am trying to avoid rolling out my own `transform_valid` function that takes an optional `extractor` function.

Is it even possible to use `filter_iterator` as an output iterator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using boost range (algorithms & adaptors) for ease of use, you'd write:

```
boost::copy(
    data | transformed(makeT) | filtered(validate) /* | indirected */, 
    std::back_inserter(queue));
```

Here is a complete working example of that:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <deque>

typedef boost::optional<int> T;
typedef std::deque<T> Q;

static T makeT(int i)
{
    if (i%2) return T();
    else     return i;
}

static bool validate(const T& optional) 
{ 
    return (bool) optional; // select the optional that had a value set
}

int main()
{
    static const int data[] =  { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    Q q;

    using boost::adaptors::filtered;
    using boost::adaptors::transformed;

    // note how Boost Range elegantly supports an int[] as an input range
    boost::copy(data | transformed(makeT) | filtered(validate), std::back_inserter(q));

    // demo output: 2, 4, 6, 8 printed
    for (Q::const_iterator it=q.begin(); it!=q.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it? "set" : "unset") << "\t" << it->get_value_or(0) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

With a little help from this answer: [Use boost::optional together with boost::adaptors::indirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123327/use-boostoptional-together-with-boostadaptorsindirected)

I now include an elegant demonstration of using the `indirected` range adaptor as well for immediate output of the queue (dereferencing the optionals):

> <sub>Note that for (smart) pointer types there would *obviously* be no need to provide the `pointee<>` specialisation. I reckon this is by design: *[`optional<> is not, and does not model, a pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/development.html#id555831)*</sub>

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>

namespace boost {
    template<typename P> struct pointee<optional<P> > {
        typedef typename optional<P>::value_type type;
    };
}

typedef boost::optional<int> T;

static T    makeT(int i)                { return i%2?  T() : i; }
static bool validate(const T& optional) { return (bool) optional; }

int main() {
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    static int data[] =  { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    boost::copy(data | transformed(makeT) 
                     | filtered(validate) 
                     | indirected, 
                     std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about adaptors, the pipeline syntax looks really nifty.

Comment: edited: showing the `indirected` range adaptor now as well, to dereference the optionals on the fly

Comment: could we, therefore, use such syntax `boost::copy(data | transformed(makeT) | filtered(validate) | indirected, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));` ? (I wonder if we could skip the validate phase, ie if indirected is smart enough to handle null pointers).

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes we could (I just followed the OP about inserting into a `deque`). No, you cannot skip the validation, because dereferencing an `optional<>` asserts `this->is_initialized()` (or would return a reference to a rogue memory location)

Comment: @Matthieu: just expended the exercise to minimize the second example into a full test app in 20 LoC

Comment: very nice! Too bad there is no `indirected` does not skip null pointers automatically, but I guess it's not an obvious behavior :D

Comment: @MatthieuM. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3023/discussion-between-sehe-and-matthieu-m)

Comment: @sehe:  Great.  That is elegant.  Is the "|" lazy?  I assume it is.

Comment: @zrb: it _can_ be, depending on the source iterator. If the source range is an input iterator range (modeling the SingelPassRng concept), then some of the adapters are 'out' (reversed, e.g. requires a BiDirectionalRng) but others (filtered, uniqued, transformed) are just fine. **Note that the *composition* of range adaptors is _always_ lazy** ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/general_requirements.html) _note the bolded text_). It's just that actual lazy enumeration may not be applicable to all adaptors.

Comment: I think `boost::pointee<T>::type` is just Boost's C++03 mechanism of accomplishing the same thing as something like `decltype(*std::declval<T>())`. I.e., its intended use is to determine the result type of [*any* dereferenceable object](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/pointee.html), not just pointers, so IMO it's not entirely relevant that "*`optional<>` is not, and does not model, a pointer*".

Comment: @ildjam: I was conjecturing this as a possible explanation for the fact that this feature, though reported missing ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977339/c-range-xrange-equivalent-in-stl-or-boost/2421236#2421236)), has not been implemented (fixed?) since. Thanks for actually reading up on the intended goals. I think you may be right;