# How to filter or "grep" a C++ vector?

Tags: c++

I've got a `vector<MyType>` and would like another `vector<MyType>` containing only those MyTypes which fulfill some simple criteria, e.g. that some data member equals something. What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `copy_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>  // for copy_if
#include <iterator>   // for back_inserter

std::vector<MyType> v2;
std::copy_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2),
             [](MyType const & x) { return simple_citerion(x); } );
```

Comment: But it's important to note that `copy_if` is only in C++11, right?

Comment: @EitanT: You can abuse `remove_copy_if` for C++03, though, by inverting the predicate.

Comment: @Xeo Yes. I was thinking along the lines of creating a vector copy and then using `v2.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), simple_criterion), str.end);`

Comment: @EitanT: That involves a lot of unnecessary copies / destructions, though, and you need to traverse the space twice.

Answer (score 7):

Using a little bit of Boost, you can:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,-9,3};

for (auto i : v | filtered(_arg1 >=0))
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

This sample uses Phoenix for implicit lambdas defined by expression template (`_arg1 >= 0`), but you can use any callable (C++03 or higher) with Boost adaptors (fitlered, transformed, reversed etc)

See here for more showcase material and a full example:

- [Is it possible to use boost::filter_iterator for output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254131/is-it-possible-to-use-boostfilter-iterator-for-output/7254598#7254598)

Comment: Another good way, and you can extend Boost.Range to create a new vector from the filtered result, if you need to, without saving the result to a temporary.