# What is the effect of the pipe operator in c++ boost::adaptors::filtered?

Tags: c++, boost

In [`boost::adaptors::filtered`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) the filter function is used likeso:

```
std::vector<int> input;
input += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;

boost::copy(
        input | filtered(is_even()),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
```

What is the effect of the pipe operator in this case? It is not defined for `std::vector`, is it an overload? If so, how does one effectively search for such operators in libraires like boost?

Comment: i am already lost at `input += 1,2,...`.

Comment: @user463035818 Thanks for the solidarity, one normally has to be afraid to admit such things.

Comment: Effective searching: IDE to the rescue, Visual Studio Code using C/C++ (ms-vscode.cpptools) gives on hover the following tooltip: `boost::range_detail::filtered_range<...> boost::range_detail::operator|<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int>>, is_even>(std::__1::vector<...> &r, const boost::range_detail::filter_holder<...> &f)

+2 overloads
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Boost Range **Adaptor**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html). Some more documentation has been written in this [online book "The Boost C++ Libraries"](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.range-adaptors).

There are many such ranges, which can be composed to write high-level functional effect. Examples are here:

- [Why is there no transform_if in the C++ standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579832/why-is-there-no-transform-if-in-the-c-standard-library/23579922#23579922)
- [Is it possible to use boost::filter_iterator for output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254131/is-it-possible-to-use-boostfilter-iterator-for-output/7254598#7254598)

### The `filtered` adaptor

`input | filtered(is_even())` creates a temporary instance of the adaptor type:

```
boost::range_detail::filtered_range<is_even, std::vector<int> >
```

That's a type that models the Range Concept and holds a reference to the source range (`input`) as well as a copy of the filter predicate (`is_even()`).

The Range Concept is then implemented such that iteration of the range yields a bidirectional range as if it had only the elements of the source range that satisfy the filter predicate. You could equally write:

```
is_even predicate;
for (auto const& i : input)
    if (predicate(i))
        std::cout << i << ",";
```

`range | adaptor` is an expression template that generates a new *adapted* range.

### How/Why Does It Work With `|`?

The real answer is "because that's how it's designed and documented". The more technical explanation is because `filtered(is_even())` is of type `boost::range_detail::filter_holder<is_even>` which has an overloaded `operator |`:

```
template< class SinglePassRange, class Predicate >
inline filtered_range<Predicate, SinglePassRange>
operator|(SinglePassRange& r,
          const filter_holder<Predicate>& f)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT((SinglePassRangeConcept<SinglePassRange>));
    return filtered_range<Predicate, SinglePassRange>( f.val, r );
}
```

> Note: The assert only verifies the **minimum** required traversal category. As documented you'll get ["The minimum of the range category of rng and Bidirectional Range"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html), which is a Bidirectional Range in this case (because vector has random traversal).

### The Other Thing

> I am already lost at input += 1,2,.... – user463035818 56 mins ago

That's Boost Assign, unrelated to the range adaptor, I'd venture that C++11 makes it largely obsolete, because you can easily say

```
std::vector<int> input { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Or indeed

```
std::vector<int> input;
input.insert(input.end(), { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
```

Comment: +1 for quoting my highly qualified statement :P. To be honest I was almost certain that this code must be an april foolsday joke. Out of curiosity i tried to implement this `+= 1,2,3` stuff, it is surprisingly easy, but I agree that it obsolete, I would even say it is a not nice usage of operator overloading.

Comment: btw at least I was most interested in the " If so, how does one effectively search for such operators in libraires like boost?" part of the question, which you dont really adress in your answer

Comment: @user463035818 You don't. You just look at the code, see `using namespace boost::assign` and go from there. It's questionable library design, though I understand people were in desperate need for succinct container initializers before c++11. (And, of course I don't address that part in my answer, because it was never part of the question, which was posted by someone else, even :))